# how to fetch the column name in related table in Toad?

Tags: oracle, toad

how to fetch the column name in related table in Toad? For example, 
Table Name: User;
 Column name: Usr_code

```
Select * from User where u
```

after where condition, related column should be coming in drop down? send the shortcut?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want to know what are the columns of table `User`?

- From Oracle metadata:

  ```
  select * from all_tab_columns where table_name ='USER';
  ```
- From Toad UI: You should use an alias, then shortcut for **autocompletion** is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> if I remember correctly. So start with the below and use kbd shortcut after you entered the last dot `.`:
- Depending on the TOAD configuration, it can also be <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>

  ```
  Select * from User u where u.<ctrl>+<space>
  ```

  or

  ```
  Select * from User u where u.<ctrl>+<.>
  ```

Comment: J.Chomel: It's not Working. It's Shows some statement details only

Comment: Yah. Right, It's working. But if we're not using alias name, Not working.

Comment: The way i know if it's too use alias. Good luck, keep us posted if you find better way

Answer (score 0):

To fetch the columns names from a table, I use the following:

```
SELECT * FROM [table name] WHERE ROWNUM < 1;
```